# Can I lock the width or height of an MFC dialog during resizing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, resize

Is there a way to lock a dialog box's size in one direction (restrict only width or only height) in MFC?

Comment: Do you mean *other* than making the dialog non-resizeable? I can't imagine a better way than that to lock the width *and* height.

Comment: yes, I mean making it non-resizeable on one dimension (not both). how to do it using MFC CDialog api?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to override `OnGetMinMaxInfo`. In OnInitDialog you can capture the current height, and then use it for both minimum and maximum height. Call `__super::OnGetMinMaxInfo` first and then only change the height members. Note that the window may not exist the first couple times OnGetMinMaxInfo are called.

Here's a [detailed article on GetMinMaxInfo](http://www.flounder.com/getminmaxinfo.htm).

Comment: +1 this is the correct solution. Also, nice link to Joseph Newcomer's website. This is a great resource for MFC developers. Although I personally don't make much use of `__super`; it can be easily replaced with `CDialog` in this example to minimize ambiguity.

Comment: Great Link, I've used that page before when I was doing the exact same thing in MFC.

Comment: `__super` is nice if you rename a class's base, so you don't have to find-replace the existing base calls.